# Laravel - How to find foreign key value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, xampp

first time working with Laravel and PHP. I am trying to insert row in the table **profile** where the attribute uID is a foreign key referencing to uID on **user** table, but getting errors. How do I insert just the summary attribute of the profile and set the uID (foreign key) automatically. I can insert users with uID without any problems. Here are my model and controller files. Thanks!

user model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class user extends Model
    {
    // specify which attributes can be filled out during registration
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable=['firstname','lastname','email','password',];

    public function profile(){
      return $this->hasOne(profile::class);
    }
}
```

profile model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class profile extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['summary',];

    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo(user::class);
    }
}
```

profile migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
     // create profile table
       Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('pID');
           $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
           $table->string('summary')->default('');
           $table->unsignedInteger('uID');

           $table->foreign('uID')->references('uID')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
       });
   }
}
```

profile controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\profile;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('profile.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // used to store user profile after validation
        $this->validate($request,[
          'summary' => 'required'
        ]);
        $profile = new profile([
          'summary' => $request->get('summary'),
          'uID' => $request->user()->uID
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.create')->with('success','Profile created');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Laravel :)

On your profile Model on the user method you need to define the foreign key.

`public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo(user::class, 'uID');
 }`

If you don't provide the foreign key, it will look for `user_id` field.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a couple of things that could need to be sort out:

1. Declare your Classes with a `capitalised letter`. It is `Profile` not `profile`. Avoid plurals as well. More on that can be explored reading about `PSR-x`;
2. You have deviated from the laravel way in regards to `foreign keys`. Therefore, you need to specify in your relationship which are the keys to connect with:

**Also, notice how I changed your method name from user -> users**

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(user::class, 'id', 'uID');
}
```

As well as for your profile relationship:

```
public function profiles(){
    return $this->hasOne(profile::class, 'uID', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi put your database here and add forign key to the model